# The inheritance of attributes using __init__

Tags: python, inheritance, attributes, polymorphism

I'm Java person who just started learning Python. Take this example:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, name, phone):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone

class Teenager(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, phone, website):
        self.name=name
        self.phone=phone
        self.website=website
```

I'm sure there's a lot of redundant code (I know in Java, there are a lot of redundancies for the bit of code above).

Which parts are redundant with respect to which attributes are already inherited from the parent class?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

When writing the `__init__` function for a class in python, you should always call the `__init__` function of its superclass. We can use this to pass the relevant attributes directly to the superclass, so your code would look like this:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, phone):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
class Teenager(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, phone, website):
        Person.__init__(self, name, phone)
        self.website=website
```

As others have pointed out, you could replace the line

```
Person.__init__(self, name, phone)
```

with

```
super(Teenager, self).__init__(name, phone)
```

and the code will do the same thing. This is because in python `instance.method(args)` is just shorthand for `Class.method(instance, args)`. If you want use `super` you need to make sure that you specify `object` as the base class for `Person` as I have done in my code.

The [python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) has more information about how to use the `super` keyword. The important thing in this case is that it tells python to look for the method `__init__` in a superclass of `self` that is not `Teenager`

Comment: Note that if you are using Python 2.x, you must explicitly list `object` as a base class of `Person` in order to use `super()`. Otherwise, you have to use the `Person.__init__` form.

Comment: @chepner can you provide a reference for that? I can't find one.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super indicates that super() is only supported on new-style classes, which in Python 2.x are those that inherit from `object`

Comment: @chepner Thanks. I did not realize python classes do not automatically inherit from a common base class the way they do in Java. I have fixed my code.

Answer (score 30):

Slightly cleaner way I like to do this:

```
class Teenager(Person):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           self.website=kwargs.pop('website')
           super(Teenager, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

It doesn't make much of a difference in this case, but when you have an `__init__` with a ton of arguments, it makes life easier.

Comment: Upvoted for use of *args and **kwargs (... efficient in the case of a numerous arguments).

Comment: Using ``args`` and ``kwargs`` generally leads to inconsistent behaviour. Explicitly taking a keyword from ``kwargs`` means ``Teenager('a', 'b', 'c')`` will *not* work correctly. It fails with a KeyError, as ``website`` is ``args[2]`` in this case.

Answer (score 23):

All of the examples so far have been for Python 2.x but here's a solution for Python 3.x that makes use of a shorter version of super() and doesn't inherit from object.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, phone):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone

class Teenager(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, phone, website):
        super().__init__(name, phone)
        self.website = website
```

Answer (score 7):

Attributes in Python are not inherited when they are defined in the constructor and parent class constructor is not called, unless you do all of it manually:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, name, phone):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone
class Teenager(Person):
    def_init_(self, name, phone, website):
        Person.__init__(self, name, phone)  # Call parent class constructor.
        self.website=website
```

More on it here: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance

Answer (score 3):

With reference to @Tom answer who suggested a cleaner solution when a lot of instance attributes are involved, another approach could be the following, i.e. like @Marcin answer with the addition of `*args` and `**kwargs`:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, name, phone):
        self.name = name
        self.phone = phone

class Teenager(Person):
    def __init__(self, website, *args, **kwargs):
        self.website = website
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chris = Teenager('www.chris.com', 'chris', '802-250-5159')
```