# Query on Config module in python

Tags: python, config

i am analyzing an old framework, where one of the python file is giving me error on run. Below is the code for same

```
from config import Config

CAPTURE_CONFIG = Config(
name='CAPTURE_CONFIG',
is_saved=True,
is_modified=True)
```

Error :

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_modified'
```

I need to get rid of the error , also if some one can point out the need to define variables in Config() itself when we can pass a file  in Config(file).

Comment: What is this module? Where did it get from?

Comment: @Bharel I assume its this https://www.red-dove.com/config-doc/

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear. There is no `is_modified` argument in this object. Take out the argument for it to work.

Otherwise, you can create a class that inherits Config and assigns `is_modified`.

To inherit the `Config` class you can do something like this

```
class NewConfig(Config):
    def __init__(self, is_modified):
        super(NewConfig, self).__init__(is_modified)
        self.is_modified = is_modified
```

You can find more about inheritance in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8854054/5779280) SO post and elsewhere.

Comment: if you can elaborate your answer regarding creating a class that would be great help