# How to inherit all functionality of a parent class?

Tags: python, class, object, inheritance, super

I'm trying to inherit all of the functionality from `ete3.Tree` into my new class called `TreeAugmented` but not all of the methods and attributes are available?

Is there something I am supposed to do in `__init__` with `super`? It seems like with `super` you must specify individual attributes like in [The inheritance of attributes using __init__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853966/the-inheritance-of-attributes-using-init).

I could have another object in the class called `tree` where I store everything from `ete3.Tree` but I want to be able to use these objects with the functions in the `ete3` package.

**Is there a way to just inherit everything from the parent class?**

```
import ete3
newick = "(((petal_width:0.098798,petal_length:0.098798):0.334371,"
         "sepal_length:0.433169):1.171322,sepal_width:1.604490);"

print(ete3.Tree(newick).children)
# [Tree node '' (0x1296bf40), Tree node 'sepal_width' (0x1296bf0f)]

class TreeAugmented(ete3.Tree):
    def __init__(self, name=None, new_attribute=None):
        self.name = name # This is an attribute in ete3 namespace
        self.new_attribute = new_attribute

x = TreeAugmented(newick)
x.children
```

Traceback

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-76-de3016b5fd1b> in <module>()
      9
     10 x = TreeAugmented(newick)
---> 11 x.children

~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ete3/coretype/tree.py in _get_children(self)
    145
    146     def _get_children(self):
--> 147         return self._children
    148     def _set_children(self, value):
    149         if type(value) == list and \

AttributeError: 'TreeAugmented' object has no attribute '_children'
```

Comment: You usually call `__init__()` of the base class. How differs a bit depending on the Python version.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6 and plan on upgrading to 3.7 once all of the packages I use migrated as well. So in `__init__` I would call the `ete3.Tree` class?

Comment: https://www.python-course.eu/python3_inheritance.php

Comment: If you look at the accepted answer for the link you posted, it shows the code working without explicitly calling out all of the attributes. Any arguments that are required by the parent class will still be required, so don't forget to pass them through too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to just inherit everything from the parent class?

It is the case, by default. The child class inherits what it does not override.

You child class is almost correct. Since you override the `__init__` method, you want to make sure the `__init__` method of the parent class is called as well.

This is achieved using `super`:

```
class TreeAugmented(ete3.Tree):
    def __init__(self, newick=None, name=None, format=0, dist=None, support=None, new_attribute=None):
        super().__init__(newick=newick, format=format, dist=dist, support=support, name=name)
        self.new_attribute = new_attribute
```

No need to do `self.name = name` since it is done in `super().__init__()`. All you have to take care about is what is specific to your child class.

#### Using *args/**kwargs

Also, since you don't touch all those parent init attributes, you can make the code clearer using args/kwargs:

```
class TreeAugmented(ete3.Tree):
    def __init__(self, newick=None, new_attribute=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(newick=newick, *args, **kwargs)
        self.new_attribute = new_attribute
```

In this example, I kept `newick` as first positional and decided all other parameters come after `new_attribute` or are keyword arguments.

#### Set a parent class parameter

You don't have to expose all parameters from the parent class if you don't want to. For instance if you wanted to create a child class that would only do [format 3 "all branches + all names"](http://etetoolkit.org/docs/latest/reference/reference_tree.html), you could force the format by writing:

```
class TreeAugmented(ete3.Tree):
    def __init__(self, newick=None, name=None, dist=None, support=None, new_attribute=None):
        super().__init__(newick=newick, format=3, dist=dist, support=support, name=name)
        self.new_attribute = new_attribute
```

(This is just a dummy example to expose a common practice. It probably does not make sense in your context.)

Comment: or `*args, **kwargs`

Comment: I'm getting a duplicate error for `newick` but I only use it once in the call `TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'newick'`

Comment: Sorry. My fault. Don't pass `self` to `super().__init__()`. Answer fixed.

Comment: Thank you! Is `self` inducing that behavior because `newick` is in the arguments in both?

Comment: self and newick are the first positional arguments. The method expects (self, newick,...), and since it is bound, self is passed automatically, but since I also passed it (my mistake), the method receives (self, self, newick=whatever), then maps self to self, self to newick, then newick to newick... hence the error. I hope I'm making sense.