# I want to not have to respecify parent attributes of an object when adding attributes from a child class

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, parent-child

So I have this dataset of stars that I'm creating a class for (Star). And of those stars some of them are variable stars. I created a child class (Variable), but when I determine one of my Star objects is a variable star (code not included), I want to include extra information to that same object without having to respecify the old information, and further categorize the object into a child class.

I know I can get it to work if I do something like this:

```
# Class attribute
category = 'variable'

# Initializer / Instance attributes
def __init__(self, name, coordinates, scatter, photometry, periods, amplitudes):
```

and then:

```
star1 = Variable('Star 1', ('RA', 'dec'), 0.1, np.sin(np.linspace(0,1,100)), [1,100,1000], [1,2,1])
```

But I don't want to have to respecify all of that information.

```
# Parent class
    class Star:

    # Class attribute
    category = 'TESS'

# Initializer / Instance attributes
def __init__(self, name, coordinates, scatter):
    self.name = name
    self.coordinates = coordinates
    self.scatter = scatter

star1 = Star('Star 1', ('RA', 'dec'), 0.1)
print('Parent class')
print('category    :', star1.category)
print('name        :', star1.name)
print('coordinates :', star1.coordinates)
print('scatter     :', star1.scatter, '\n')

# Child class (inherits from Star() class)
class Variable(Star):

    # Class attribute
    category = 'variable'

    # Initializer / Instance attributes
    def __init__(self, photometry, periods, amplitudes):
        self.photometry = photometry
        self.periods = periods
        self.amplitudes = amplitudes

star1 = Variable(np.sin(np.linspace(0,1,100)), [1,100,1000], [1,2,1])
print('Child class')
print('category   :', star1.category)
print('photometry :', star1.photometry)
print('periods    :', star1.periods)
print('amplitudes :', star1.amplitudes)
```

The code below works as expected. But, if i try:

```
print(star1.name)
```

after:

```
star1 = Variable(np.sin(np.linspace(0,1,100)), [1,100,1000] [1,2,1])
```

name, coordinates, and scatter seem to be deleted from my object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The inheritance of attributes using \_\_init\_\_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853966/the-inheritance-of-attributes-using-init)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call the superclass's initialization method, otherwise it won't ever run! In other words, the Star class's `__init__` method doesn't run unless you tell it to.

```py
class Variable(Star):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        super().__init__(arg1)
        self.arg2 = arg2
```

`super()` is a way of accessing the superclass and its methods. So say you had a `merge` method in the `Star` class that merged two stars and you wanted to call it from within the `Variable` class, you would call `super().merge(other_star)`.

Comment: I still have to specify the stars name, coordinates, and scatter when I reclass star1 as a variable star.

Comment: Yes you do because to make a Star, you've declared that the user needs to pass in a name, coordinates, and a scatter. So at some point you have to specify what those variables are.